# Unable to create output file error

Tags: configuration, views

I have inherited a Drupal site and I'm trying to debug some issues. I am fairly new to Drupal.

I have copied the site to a different server to use as a test environment.
The site seems to be working fine except that when I try to output a pre-existing 'report' as PDF, but I got the the following error

> TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file:
>   /home2/freelond/public_html/sites/all/pdf/historic_report/agilityweb-2013-09-18-1246.pdf

The location referred to is the original server and not the new one (hence the error)
I cant see where to set the path for the output file.

The site settings have all been changed (as far as I am aware) in Configuration and I can see any setting specific to this module for this (but may not be seeing wood for the trees!)

I have also cleared caches.

Can anyone suggest anything here?

Comment: The problem seems to be of files directory ("sites/default/files"), either the directory is not present or it doesn't have the appropriate permission.

Comment: May be temp file is not configured properly. You can check in admin "File settings" for the temp file, if this is correct or not.

Comment: The location referred to /home2/freelond/public_html/sites/all/ is on the original server however location specified in file settings is /home/oadminc/tmpdir. it seems to be trying to open a file on the old server and ignoring the locaation specified in file settings.